# Global variables not defined in php

Tags: php

I'm have a class that uses a function called by the __construct to assign values to class variables. The variables however are gives errors say undefined.

```
session_start();

class request{
  private $sService;
  private $sNote;
  private $iAffectedUserId;
  private $iUserId;
  private $sPassword;
  private $sFirstName;
  private $sLastName;

function __construct($sService, $oData){
    $this->init_Session_Variables();
    $this->$sService = $sService;
}

private function init_Session_Variables(){
    $this->$iUserId = $_SESSION['user_Id'];
    $this->$sPassword = $_SESSION['password'];
    $this->$sFirstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];
    $this->$sLastName = $_SESSION['lastName'];
}
}
```

Why are my class variables returning error of undefined when I'm trying to assign values to them in the init_Session_Variables()?

EDIT:

Error:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: iUserId in **C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\MyVyn\Utils\utils\php\userQuery.php** on line **57**

Comment: When you receive an error, you should post the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variables are accessed like:

```
$this->iUserId
```

in the local context.

```
$this->$iUserId
```

would be the equivalent of

```
$iUserId = 'x';
$this->x;
```

that is to say, its like a variable variable, `$this->$iUserId` is `$this->"whatever $userId is set to"`

Comment: The results did not change. still showing undefined. I'm trying to assign first, before accessing.

Comment: I'd `var_dump($_SESSION['user_Id']);` and make sure it, itself is defined

Comment: Okay, I thought I was suppose to refer to the value directly to set it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your assignation is incorrect, you should use for example:

```
$this->sService = $sService;
```

Also, they are not global variables, they are class variables.

Comment: I meant global within the class. The $sService is fine and works exactly how I need. It's the init_Session_Variables() that isn't working out.

Comment: I don't see how it works... but you need to correct your assignation everywhere.